# sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchColumnError: "Could not locate column in row for column '0'"

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

So I've got this code to connect to redshift using python from a linux server.
It throws me the sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchColumnError: "Could not locate column in row for column '0'" error when I try to get the tables from the redshift server.

Other that have experienced and error similar to this solved it by updating python packages, I did all of mine earlier today but I'm still getting the error.

Versions:

Python 2.7.12

SQLAlchemy 1.1.6

sqlalchemy-redshift 0.5.0

psycopg2 2.7

Here's the code, I'm using the console_login:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import getpass
import json
def getredshiftconnect(console_login=True, login_credentials_file=None):
try:
    if console_login:
        login = getpass.getpass("Username: ")
        password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
        server = input("Server: ")
        database = input("Database connecting to: ")
        schema = input("Schema connecting to: ")
        engine = create_engine("redshift+psycopg2://{0}:{1}@{2}:<PortNumber>/{3}"\
                                   .format(login, password, server, database))
    else:
        # Read JSON file with login credentials
        # Make sure that fields are referenced correctly, i.e.:
        # login, password, server, database
        login_credentials = json.load(open(login_credentials_file,"r"))
        engine = create_engine("redshift+psycopg2://{0}:{1}@{2}:<PortNumber>/{3}"\
                                   .format(login_credentials["login"],
                                           login_credentials["password"],
                                           login_credentials["server"],
                                           login_credentials["database"]))
    # To test connection, if able to list tables then login was succesful
    # Pick a schema that actually has tables
    if engine.table_names(schema): # Explodes at this call
        print ("Successfully connected")
        return engine
    else:
        print ("Not properly connected")
except Exception as e:
    print ("Error Connecting: ", e)
```

Answer (score 3):

I did figure out that SQLAlchemy-1.1.6 is the cause of the issue.
After downgrade to 1.1.5 it is working fine again in my case.

```
pip install SQLAlchemy==1.1.5
```

Note: I found out that the latest version of SQLAlchemy has some more bugs.
Also I had to remove and reinstall SQLAlchemy on some servers to solve the issue (e.g. pip uninstall SQLAlchemy).

Comment: Also solved my problem. But in my case I was using sqlalchemy 1.1.9. Thanks

Comment: Update for 2020. Ran into this same issue. Solved it by downgrading from 1.3.18 ==> 1.2.15